# Is the new design a keeper?

Tags: discussion, design

There have been some fairly negative comments on the new design, some constructive and some less.

I think the following purely aesthetical question is therefore warranted:

Do you like the new design?

Please choose below.

<sup>(do not add other answers and do not down vote the answers if possible)</sup>

Comment: Well, at first I didn't liked it, but now after I got used to it it starts to look good. Must be some people-don't-like-change effect.

Comment: I believe that recently the site has changed its theme again. This makes this question obsoleted, since it was asked on 2012. Maybe you want to lock it?

Answer (score 21):

## I do not like it

We should go back to the simple design and re-think how the site should look.

Comment: SE is generally very good at turning out nice clean designs that make the information on the page easy to process. This is not one of them.

Comment: I think there are too many problems.  Its not that this design is bad but I do not care for how it turned out.  I think the meta actually looks better.

Comment: That yellow and those hard edges in the main title get in my face too much.  Some of the old logo ideas were better than what we ended up with.

Answer (score 9):

## I like it

I like the new design. We should keep it, do the tweaks as requested [here](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design) and fix any other bugs that emerge.

Comment: I am starting to like it, but I must accept this was not my first impression

Answer (score 1):

I have used SE sites for a while and today I just signed up for Skeptics.

I must say the background design is VERY confusing for someone used to the other SE sites where the background is just a single plain color. I kept thinking I wasn't on the main page yet.