# I don't see anything good in the new design?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is the new design a keeper?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1548/is-the-new-design-a-keeper)

High contract is not a good setting where the site has more readable contents.

It does not look that friendly

Yellow black is a bad choice

Can we just bring the old site back. I know it has some problems but at least we lived with it and was more friendly.

Comment: Related: http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1601/choice-of-colours-in-the-new-design-does-not-represent-our-brand